# Cisco VEN501-AT wireless access point password

Tags: passwords, home-networking, wireless-access-point, dsl

I just got DSL from AT&T, and their gateway (router + modem, model 3801HGV) only supports 802.11b/g wifi -- which is kind of pokey at this point. (It's faster than the internet connection, but I'm concerned about transferring files between computers on my home network.) However, the install also included a Cisco VEN501-AT wireless access point -- intended to connect to the wireless TV receiver. There's not much data out there on the VEN501-AT ([here](http://forums.att.com/t5/Receivers-Battery-Backup/Cisco-VEN501-Login/td-p/4177590)'s some), but it apparently supports 802.11n at 5 GHz only.

They may have chosen different frequencies so that TV and internet traffic wouldn't get in eachothers wireless way. However, I won't be using the TV that much, so connecting my computer to the VEN501-AT seems like an easy way to get a faster wireless signal.

My problem is that I don't know the username/password to its web interface.

Does anyone know the (default) username/password?

FWIW, [this](http://www.amt.com/images/products//VEN501_VIDEO-BRIDGE-SOLUTION_AMT.pdf) page claims to have the information, but it doesn't work for me.

The VEN501-AT does have a WPS button, so I might be able to use that. Still, I'd like to have access to the web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found on [AT&T Community Forums](https://forums.att.com/t5/Receivers-Battery-Backup/Cisco-VEN501-Login/td-p/4177590)

> Posted Jan 1, 2015 by rdljr
>
> Cisco VEN501 Login
> Username= ATTadmin
> Password= 501!VeN

Comment: i was actually wondering, is this AP able to be put into bridge mode? i cannot find an option for it but i need to connect another ap from across my house to it

Answer (score 0):

There is no web interface. It is non configurable. It is designed solely for Wireless STBs and that's it. WPS button will not work for a computer either. The WPS button is for first time connection to the STB. However if you had another VEN501 through a different provider (Telus as an example) you can flip the swith in the back to client mode and connect two of more VEN501 together turning it into a wireless bridge

Comment: This is simply false. The user/password is ATTadmin/501!VeN and it is configurable like many other wireless access points. The interface looks like those on linksys routers, which isn't surprising since Cisco owned linksys.